# Change in adding listbox to sheet from vertical to horizontal and load all results in listbox

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

After successfully loading my data into a listbox, I was told that the data should be orientated horizontally not vertically.  How can implement the new specifications?

Here is the desired result:

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    With Me.lsbWarenausgang
        For k = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(k) = True Then
                For i = 1 To 9
                    Worksheets("Tabelle5").Cells(i, 1) = Me.lsbWarenausgang.List(k, i - 1)
                Next i
            End If
        Next k
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a helper array (with same size as listbox columns) to fill with current selected listbox row and then write it down in excel sheet

as for this latter operation use:

- `.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)`

  to get the last non empty cell in first row
- `.Offset(, IIf(IsEmpty(.Cells), 0, 1))`

  to offset it by one column or not whether the returned range by previous method is a non empty cell or not
- `.Resize(9)` method to reference a 1 column range with same rows as the array

so you can code:

```
    Option Explicit

    Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
        Dim i As Long, k As Long
        Dim arr(1 To 9) As Variant

        With Me.lsbWarenausgang
            For k = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                If .Selected(k) Then
                    For i = 1 To 9
                        arr(i) = .List(k, i - 1)
                    Next i
                    With Worksheets("Tabelle5")
                        With .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
                            .Offset(, IIf(IsEmpty(.Cells), 0, 1)).Resize(9) = Application.Transpose(arr)
                        End With
                    End With
                End If
            Next k
        End With
    End Sub
```